# Gráfico: Cargar datos en un HTML con Highcharts.js y mostrar en WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, .net, highcharts

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto donde tengo que filtrar un archivo csv y mostrarlo en un gráfico a través de unos plugings js (HighCharts), los cuales me generan una serie de gráficos con los datos que yo le mando.

Tengo un archivo index.html donde tengo cargado las llamadas a los scripts y tengo cargado el csv.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente; como puedo pasarle los datos del csv, previamente cargado en un DataGrid dentro de vb.NEt 2012, para generar los graficos?

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<pre id="csv" style="display:none">Year,Annual mean,5 year mean
1880,-0.31,
1881,-0.22,
1882,-0.28,-0.29
1883,-0.3,-0.29
1884,-0.33,-0.3
1885,-0.32,-0.32
1886,-0.29,-0.32
1887,-0.35,-0.28
1888,-0.28,-0.3
1889,-0.18,-0.3
1890,-0.4,-0.3
1891,-0.29,-0.31
1892,-0.33,-0.34
1893,-0.34,-0.32
1894,-0.35,-0.3
1895,-0.27,-0.26
1896,-0.19,-0.26
1897,-0.16,-0.22
1898,-0.3,-0.19
1899,-0.19,-0.19
1900,-0.11,-0.21
1901,-0.18,-0.22
1902,-0.28,-0.25
1903,-0.32,-0.28
1904,-0.36,-0.29
1905,-0.27,-0.32
1906,-0.22,-0.33
1907,-0.42,-0.33
1908,-0.36,-0.35
1909,-0.37,-0.38
1910,-0.36,-0.36
1911,-0.37,-0.36
1912,-0.34,-0.32
1913,-0.34,-0.27
1914,-0.17,-0.25
1915,-0.11,-0.26
1916,-0.31,-0.27
1917,-0.39,-0.28
1918,-0.35,-0.3
1919,-0.22,-0.27
1920,-0.22,-0.24
1921,-0.16,-0.22
1922,-0.27,-0.22
1923,-0.23,-0.22
1924,-0.24,-0.2
1925,-0.19,-0.18
1926,-0.04,-0.16
1927,-0.17,-0.17
1928,-0.15,-0.15
1929,-0.29,-0.15
1930,-0.11,-0.14
1931,-0.04,-0.15
1932,-0.1,-0.12
1933,-0.22,-0.12
1934,-0.1,-0.13
1935,-0.15,-0.1
1936,-0.07,-0.04
1937,0.04,-0.02
2005,0.63,0.57
2006,0.56,0.54
2007,0.59,0.56
2008,0.44,0.56
2009,0.57,0.55
2010,0.64,0.54
2011,0.52,0.59
2012,0.57,0.61
2013,0.62,
2014,0.69,</pre>
```

Codigo que llama a los datos y muestra la grafica:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Global temperature change'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Data input from CSV'
    },

    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        lineWidth: 1
    }, {
        type: 'areaspline',
        color: '#c4392d',
        negativeColor: '#5679c4',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }]
});
```

Dentro de la etiqueta  `<pre>`  tengo que cargar el archivo csv el cual mando desde vb.net.
Como puedo mandarlo como parámetro ?

Comment: queres pasarle parametros a index.html?

Comment: si !! el contenido del csv ! quiero pasarlo como parametro al index.html, donde tengo la funcion.

Comment: podrias mostrar algo del contenido del html.. con que lenguaje haces las llamadas a los scripts?

Comment: lo acabo de cargar perdonad

Comment: dentro de que etiqueta??? los js esos leen los datos desde dentro del html?

Comment: dentro de la etiqueta <pre> se albergan los datos que necesito para crear la gráfica, ahora mismo  los datos están cargados a pelo como se pueden ver, separados por comas; pero estos mismos datos los tengo cargados dentro de un dataGrid dentro de vb.nET (archivo csv)

Comment: mi primer y mas rapida idea seria re armar el html en cada llamada..

Comment: La idea de @gbianchi es la correcta, de hecho lo he utilizado y ha funcionado a la perfección. Lo que debes hacer es mediante un StreamWriter y un FileReader leer el archivo index.html y completarlo con los parámetros. Una forma facil de esto sería en el index.html en vez de tener las etiquetas <pre> dejar algo como {REMPLAZO} y luego en memoria conviertes index.html en string y haces String.Replace("{REMPLAZO}","<pre>parámetros</pre>") Una vez que lo llenas (es decir, lo cargas en memoria - luego lo modificas - y lo guardas) lo llamas como un Source del WebBrowser.

Comment: Ahora que releo la pregunta hace falta que aclares algunas cosas @Sam.Gold como por ejemplo: ¿Qué tienen que ver entre si lo del CSV con el Datagridview? 
Tu dices algo como "dentro de la etiqueta  *csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML* debo cargar el archivo que mando desde vb.net". Eso no es claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo plantié en mi comentario:

- Puedes llenar los datos almacenados en el CSV en un **DataTable**, si lees el CSV en el código .NET (mencionaste un DataGridView, por ende los debes tener en código).
- Luego es preciso que abras el HTML y recorras los datos del **DataTable** y rellenes el HTML con dicha información.
- Finalmente guardas el HTML y con el WebBrowser lo navegas/ejecutas .

Tu HTML puede quedar con una estructura similar a:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<pre id="csv" style="display:none">{CODIGO_REEMPLAZO}</pre>
```

Y tu proyecto en .NET tendrá un código similar a:

```
 Private Sub btnVisualizar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVisualizar.Click
        Dim DT_MiInfo As DataTable

        Dim CODIGO_HTML As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\ubicacion_de_mi_archivo\ejemplo.html")

        Dim Parametros_A_Cargar As New ArrayList

        For x = 0 To DT_MiInfo.Rows.Count - 1
            ' Ten en cuenta que los nombres de los campos, MiInfo1, MiInfo2, deben ser los nombres de los campos de tu DataTable'
            Parametros_A_Cargar.Add(DT_MiInfo.Rows(x).Item("MiInfo1") & "," & DT_MiInfo.Rows(x).Item("MiInfo2") & "," & DT_MiInfo.Rows(x).Item("MiInfo3"))
        Next

        Dim String_De_Parametros As String = [String].Join(vbCrLf, Parametros_A_Cargar.ToArray())

        Dim CODIGO_HTML_FINAL As String = CODIGO_HTML.Replace("{CODIGO_REEMPLAZO}", String_De_Parametros)

        IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\ubicacion_de_mi_archivo\ejemplo.html", CODIGO_HTML_FINAL)

        WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\ubicacion_de_mi_archivo\ejemplo.html")

    End Sub
```